# Export only the data registered by the user / Django import-export

Tags: django, export-to-excel, django-import-export

Products can be exported in excel format from the `Product` table. But all the user's products are exported.

How can I export only `request.user`'s products?

Here is view :

```
def export_excel(request):
    dataset = ProductResource().export()
    response = HttpResponse(dataset.xlsx, content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=Products-" + str(datetime.datetime.now().date())+".xlsx" 
    
    return response
```

Here is resources.py :

```
class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):

author = Field() 
brand_id = Field() 

class Meta:
    model = Product

    fields = ["id", "author", "brand_id", "name", "barcode", "unit"]
    export_order = ["id", "author", "brand_id", "name", "barcode", "unit"]

def dehydrate_author(self, product: Product) -> str:
    return f"{product.author.username}" 

def dehydrate_brand_id(self, product: Product) -> str:
    return f"{product.brand_id.name}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to do, you can pass a queryset to `export()`:

```py
def export_excel(request):
    # adjust as required
    qs = Product.objects.filter(product__author__username=request.user.username)
    dataset = ProductResource().export(qs)
    # ...
    
    return response
```

In case it helps, note also that import-export provides a UI interface for export via [Admin integration](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#admin-integration).